# Executing JavaScript in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to execute the following JavaScript on the backend by recreating the logic with C# code. I'm trying to obtain the "sucuri_cloudproxy_js" cookie in order to access webcontent, but in order to obtain this cookie, you must execute this JavaScript. What is the most efficient way to execute javascript in C#? Thank you!

```
var s = {},
u, c, U, r, i, l = 0,
a, e = eval,
w = String.fromCharCode,
sucuri_cloudproxy_js = '',
S = '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';
L = S.length;
U = 0;
r = '';
var A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
for (u = 0; u < 64; u++) {
    s[A.charAt(u)] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
c = s[S.charAt(i)];
U = (U << 6) + c;
l += 6;
    while (l >= 8) {
    ((a = (U >>> (l -= 8)) & 0xff) || (i < (L - 2))) && (r += w(a));
    }
}
e(r);
```

Comment: `obtain the "sucuri_cloudproxy_js" cookie` - When it comes to writing web sites JavaScript is designed to run at the front end (in the browser). It will never obtain a cookie from the browser if you try to execute it server side (using c#). If you want a browser cookie in your running c# code then you can do that using c#.

Comment: "most efficient" is quite broad. Efficient in terms of memory? CPU? Number of cups of coffee needed to code? Also, SO is not a code writing service. If you're trying to translate JS to C#, actually try to do it, and if you get stuck on a specific part, then we might be able to help.

Comment: If you want the contents of the cookie, those are `sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_30d1993af=7c6955f33d0ecb2e874db96b607da18d` for the code you posted. Why do you want to run javascript from C# for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like some sort of base 64 decoding algorithm.  There are built in base64 decoders in C# you could try.  Alternatively, if 'S' never changes, you could just execute this in javascript and put the result in to your C# program.

executing this in javascript console:

```
var s = {},
u, c, U, r, i, l = 0,
a, e = eval,
w = String.fromCharCode,
sucuri_cloudproxy_js = '',
S = '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';
L = S.length;
U = 0;
r = '';
var A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
for (u = 0; u < 64; u++) {
    s[A.charAt(u)] = u;
}
for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
c = s[S.charAt(i)];
U = (U << 6) + c;
l += 6;
    while (l >= 8) {
    ((a = (U >>> (l -= 8)) & 0xff) || (i < (L - 2))) && (r += w(a));
    }
}
r;
```

gives this:

```
v='wE7'.charAt(2)+String.fromCharCode(99) + "" +"6su".slice(0,1) + "9su".slice(0,1) + '5' +  "5" + "fsec".substr(0,1) + "3sucur".charAt(0)+ '' + 
"3" + "" +"d".slice(0,1) +  '' +"0su".slice(0,1) +  '' +'e' +  "c" + "" +"bsucur".charAt(0)+String.fromCharCode(0x32) +  '' +''+'e' +  "8".slice(0,1) +  '' +'fK7'.charAt(2)+'@4'.slice(1,2)+"" +"d" +  '' + 
"b" + "9" +  '' +''+String.fromCharCode(54) + "b" +  '' + 
"6" + '0' +  "" +"7" + 'oMd'.charAt(2)+"asec".substr(0,1) + String.fromCharCode(49) +  '' +''+'8' +  "dsec".substr(0,1) + '';document.cookie='ssuc'.charAt(0)+ 'usuc'.charAt(0)+ 'c'+'u'+'r'+'i'+'_'+'c'.charAt(0)+'lsu'.charAt(0) +'sucuro'.charAt(5) + 'u'+'sucurd'.charAt(5) + 'psucur'.charAt(0)+ 'r'+'o'+'xsucur'.charAt(0)+ 'y'.charAt(0)+'_'+''+'usucur'.charAt(0)+ 'su'.charAt(1)+'i'+''+'d'+'_s'.charAt(0)+'3sucu'.charAt(0)  +'0'+'d'+'1'.charAt(0)+'9sucu'.charAt(0)  +'su9'.charAt(2)+'sucur3'.charAt(5) + 'asucuri'.charAt(0) + 'f'+"=" + v; location.reload();
```

take off the location.reload and execute that and it results in a string:

```
"sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_30d1993af=7c6955f33d0ecb2e874db96b607da18d"
```

all of that was originally passed through the eval function, so in the end, I'm guessing you want the 7c...18d, or maybe something to do with the uuid variable.

if S changes, then you'll need to reverse engineer this whole thing, or find a way to leverage a server side tool to execute javascript.  You could use something like phantomjs perhaps.

Comment: "sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_30d1993af=7c6955f33d0ecb2e874db96b607da18d" is exactly the cookie I need. S changes every time you try to access the page so I need a general solution. I can easily parse S but decoding it is still difficult for me.

Comment: Well, decoding S gives you the obfuscated cookie you need.  The obfuscation looks pretty basic/patterned.  You could possibly process this string down in c# if you really wanted to.  For instance, explode on + (I don't see + in v= anywhere other than string concatination.  then you'd process each piece and assemble a string.  regex on things like 'wE7'.charAt(2) to get the string and the index and index it with c#.  String.fromCharCode has similar c# methods.  Just regex out the code.  Slice is basically a substring, so regex to get the string and indices.  It can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer from Mark Evaul, the cookie content should be available in your controller code by referencing:

```
Request.Cookies["sucuri_cloudproxy_js"].Value
```

You can run the replacement algorithm on the value to decode the value of the cookie.